# C# version error when building with msbuild, ok with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, msbuild

I can build my project just fine using Visual Studio 2017; however when I use msbuild 15, I get this eror:

> error CS8306: Tuple element name 'value' is inferred. Please use language version 7.1 or greater to access an element by its inferred name.

The language version is set to 7.3 in my project file; why would I get this error when running msbuild?

Comment: what .net framework or .net core version are you using

Comment: Framework 4.7.2

Comment: have you tried building it like? msbuild YourSolution.sln /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.7.2

Comment: also, this was just implemented in May (to support 4.7.2) https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3285

Comment: Have you set the language version for both Debug and Release? Are you using the latest version of MSBuild?

Comment: Just tried the /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=4.7.2; that didn't help.

Comment: I found that the language version was not updated to 7.3 for release; however even fixing this didn't help.

Comment: You need to use msbuild 15.7.180. what version are you running?

Comment: I'm running version 15.8.166.59604; that's newer, right?

Comment: Weird... If I create a new project with the one method that msbuild was choking on and build it with msbuild, it compiles just fine - I wonder what's wrong with my main project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out - thanks to Olivier Jacot-Descombes who suggested I look in the project properties!

What I needed to do was set my C# version for all *platforms* (e.g. any CPU, x68, x64) to 7.3 in addition to setting it for all *configurations* (debug/release) as he'd suggested.

Answer (score 1):

`MSbuild 15` does not support `.NET Framework 4.7.2`.

Per the GitHub issue, this was merged in May: [github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3285](http://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3285)

Version `15.7.180` should work: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/releases/tag/v15.7.180.61344

Edit: Version `15.8.166.59604` shipped with Visual Studio 15.8, which was released in April. Though, support for .NET Framework 4.7.2, was implemented in May.

Comment: I'm running version 15.8.166.59604; isn't that newer than 15.7.180?

Comment: Hmm... So how do I get a newer version? Your 15.7.180 link is just source code... do I have to build it myself?

Comment: You can try building. Their GitHub has steps: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild

Comment: @ekolis first, try updating your Build Tools: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15

Comment: thats' where I already downloaded the build tools from just now :)